# Rsync remote folder on a server with password to local folder

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am trying to rsync folders in a remote directory on a server with password to a local directory.
SCP works but I am not able to get the right rsync command working.  I get directory not found or "not a directory" error.

I am trying:

`rsync -ratlz --rsh="/usr/bin/sshpass -p $RSYNC_PASSWORD ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l adminuser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx" $serverpath/*  $localpath/`

$serverpath has many directories with files inside of them.

The scp that works for me is :

```
for latestfile in `sshpass -p $RSYNC_PASSWORD ssh adminuser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx ls -ltr -d ${serverpath}/*`
do

sshpass -p "$RSYNC_PASSWORD" scp -r adminuser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:$serverpath/$latestfile $localpath/

done
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you need `hostname:` before `$serverpath`?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it working.  It is necessary to include hostname with server path separately.  sshpass requires user login credentials and IP of remote server as a part of the ssh command and shoudl be included it in the rsync command.

```
rsync -avzr -e "sshpass -p $RSYNC_PASSWORD ssh -l adminuser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"  adminuser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:$serverpath/*  $localpath/
```

Comment: Answering with an explanation of what you changed and why you changed it is preferable to just posting a new command line. Your answer may correctly solve this precise problem, but an explanation can enable solving more than just this one case.

Comment: oh sorry.  Will do.

Comment: What is for _-e_ option ?